# AJAX autocomplete search return div with link

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-ui

i'm working with laravel and ajax to make an autocomplete search. I'm using Jquery UI to show the results.

```
  <link rel="stylesheet"href="//codeorigin.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//codeorigin.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#busqueda").autocomplete({
            source: function (request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "{{URL('ajax/getBooksAutocomplete')}}",
                    data: {
                        busqueda: this.term
                    },
                    success: function (data) {

                        response( $.map( data, function( item ) {
                            return {label: item.title, value: item.url};
                        }));
                    },
                });
            },
        });
    });
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
     $("#busqueda2").autocomplete({

       select: function (event, ui) {
        $('#busqueda2').val(ui.item.title);
        $('#busqueda').val(ui.item.title);
       }

    });
    </script>
```

The autocomplete it's working:

[image]

but when I choose one options I'd like to redirect to the url of the option. The url: item.url

I think the result options have to be something like this:

```
<div><a href="'+ item.url +'">'+item.title+'</a></div>
```

¿How can I do that?

Edit1: My form

```
{{ Form::open(array('action' => array('BookController@getBooksAutocomplete'))) }}

{{ Form::text('busqueda', '', array('class'=>'ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all', 'id'=>'busqueda')) }}

{{ Form::close() }}
```

Comment: Use autocomplete on select function "select: function( event, ui ) {}" and get the selected item and obtain href attribute value. Now you can use document.href = URL to redirect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/phpdeveloperrahul/gN7pc/)** showing redirection to the item URL on selecting the option based on `ui.item.url` value.

JS code:

```
$(function() {
var projects = [
{
value: "yahoo",
label: "Yahoo !",
desc: "this is Yahoo !",
//icon: "jquery_32x32.png",
url:'http://yahoo.com'    
},
{
value: "bing",
label: "Bing",
desc: "This is Bing !",
//icon: "jqueryui_32x32.png",
url:'http://bing.com'    
},
{
value: "google",
label: "Google",
desc: "search engine",
//icon: "sizzlejs_32x32.png",
url:'http://google.com'
}
];
$( "#project" ).autocomplete({
minLength: 0,
source: projects,
focus: function( event, ui ) {
$( "#project" ).val( ui.item.label);
return false;
},
select: function( event, ui ) {
$( "#project" ).val( ui.item.label );
$( "#project-id" ).val( ui.item.value );
$( "#project-description" ).html( ui.item.desc );
$( "#project-icon" ).attr( "src", "images/" + ui.item.icon );
    alert("You are going to be redirected to : "+ui.item.url);
    window.location.href = ui.item.url;
return false;
}
})
.autocomplete( "instance" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
return $( "<li>" )
.append( "<a>" + item.label + "<br>" + item.desc + "</a>" )
.appendTo( ul );
};
});
```

Comment: Sorry for the question, but I'm noob using jQuery, when I tried to replace your solution in my project It wasn't working. ¿Can you help me to implement it?

Comment: Please create a fiddle of your code, so that I can look into it !

Comment: Ignore my last comment, I could do it. Thank's for all.